# nGinx load balancing not working

Tags: nginx, server, load-balancing

I've been trying to wrap my head around load balancing over the past few days and have hit somewhat of a snag. I thought that I'd set up everything correctly, but it would appear that I'm getting almost all of my traffic through my primary server still, while the weights I've set should be sending 1:10 to primary.

**My current load balancer config:**

```
upstream backend {
        least_conn;
        server 192.168.x.xx weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
        server 192.168.x.xy weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
}
server {
listen 80;
  server_name somesite.somesub.org www.somesite.somesub.org;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host somesite.somesub.org;
      proxy_pass http://backend$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
listen 443;
  server_name somesite.somesub.org www.somesite.somesub.org;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host somesite.somesub.org;
      proxy_pass http://backend$request_uri;
    }
}
```

**And my current site config** is as follows:

```bash
server {
  listen 192.168.x.xx:80;
  server_name somesite.somesub.org;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/somesite.somesub.org/html;
  access_log /var/www/somesite.somesub.org/logs/access.log;
  error_log /var/www/somesite.somesub.org/logs/error.log;
  include snippets/php.conf;
  include snippets/security.conf;
  location / {
    #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 192.168.x.xx:443 ssl http2;
  server_name somesite.somesub.org;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/somesite.somesub.org/html;
  access_log /var/www/somesite.somesub.org/logs/access.log;
  error_log /var/www/somesite.somesub.org/logs/error.log;
  include snippets/php.conf;
  include snippets/security.conf;
  include snippets/self-signed-somesite.somesub.org.conf;
}
~
```

And the other configuration is exactly the same, aside from a different IP address.

A small detail that may or may not matter: One of the nodes is hosted on the same machine of the load balancer - not sure if that matters.

Both machines have correct firewall config, and can be accessed separately.

No error logs are showing anything of use.

The only possible thing I could think of is that the nginx site config is being served before the load balancer; and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

With another look at the configuration and realized I could have just as easily had the site config that's on the load balancer listen on 127.0.0.1 and relist that among my available servers in the load balancer.

nGinx config for site on load balancer listening on localhost:80/443 solved this issue.